# RadEditor javascript error (this._contentHiddenTextarea.form) when using with RadGrid

Tags: telerik, radeditor

I'm facing the js error, and i didn't identify the reason yet.

`<telerik:RadTabStrip MultiPageID="uxMultiPage" ID="uxTabStrip" runat="server" CssClass="TabStrip">
    <Tabs>
        <telerik:RadTab meta:ResourceKey="uxTabA" PageViewID="uxTabA">
        </telerik:RadTab>
        <telerik:RadTab meta:ResourceKey="uxTabB" PageViewID="uxTabB">
        </telerik:RadTab>
        <telerik:RadTab meta:ResourceKey="uxTabC" PageViewID="uxTabC">
        </telerik:RadTab>
    </Tabs>
</telerik:RadTabStrip>`

I put 2 RadEditors in uxTabA, some aspx controls to uxTabB, and i put the RadGrid (Classic RadGrid with using AJAX built-in feature inside)- named uxGridSource in uxTabC

I'm using the ImageButton - named uxCmdSave on the CommandItem in uxGridSource .
After clicking the button uxCmdSave, everything is OK, but i'm getting the client error

Line: 310715465
Error: 'this._contentHiddenTextarea.form' is null or not an object

after that, i cannot navigate to any tab (i'm using 3 tabs as described above) on my page.
I think that this error is thrown from RadEditor, but i do not know what the solution is yet.

However, if the page is PostBack fully by any button on the page (not on the RadGrid), this error does not occurs.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this occurs when using ajax feature in classic RadGrid, and RadEditor together. But i donnot know what the solution is yet.

Any help!

Answer (score 0):

You should not mix controls from the old Telerik ASP.NET (classic) suite and the current ASP.NET AJAX one. You should switch the classic RadGrid control to the ASP.NET AJAX one and wrap it in a RadAjaxPanel to enable the Ajax functionality that was built in the classic control.

Comment: Thank for your recommendation. I solved my problem by disable built-in AJAX feature inside RadGrid, i use UpdatePanel instead. Everything is ok now. I did not migrate to new version of RadGrid because this control contains classic RadGrid is built as common control, and it is being used by anothers. I'm lazy to test this again :d

Answer (score 0):

I would try to incorporate using the same version of the controls in the application first. Mixing ASP.NET Classic controls with the ASP.NET AJAX controls can end up being tricky, and JS errors could very easily happen. I believe making the transition from one to the other should be pretty straight forward, but [here is a documentation article](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grdmigrationtoprometheus.html) regarding the switch (specifically for the RadGrid).